# Qt 4.8 "./Configure" fails

Tags: qt, qt4.8

Downloaded Qt 4.8 beta, unzipped, changed into the folder and clicked "./configure" as required.

output:
bash: ./configure: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

"Configure" is definitely there in the folder.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget it, I downloaded the “zip” file instead of the “tar.gz” file. One of the little misunderstandings caused by working exclusively under Windows for 20 years and then one day thrown to OS X/Linux waters.

Answer (score 2):

Since it has an `^M` character, the `configure` file is probably using Windows-style line endings.

Try to convert it to use UNIX-style endings:

`dos2unix configure`

Then it should run fine when you do

`./configure`

Also, the `No such file directory` refers to the interpreter specified in the configure file using the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) notation, not the configure file itself. It probably can't find it because it is searching for `/bin/sh^M` whereas it should be searching for `/bin/sh`.